# Java TangoSupport: Transforming several Cloud Point snapshots to the same space

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

I'm trying to use the TangoSupport library (Okul version) to transform several Cloud Point snapshots to the same space (using `getMatrixTransformAtTime` and `transformPointCloud`), but I have some issues:

1. The documentation doesn't match the real library.

The documentation says that the function [TangoSupport.transformPointCloud](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/support/reference/TangoSupport.TangoMatrixTransformData.html) gets float[], but in my version (and the compiler fails because of that), it needs double[].

The documentation also says that there's [TangoSupport.transformDoublePointCloud](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/support/reference/TangoSupport.html#doubleTransformPointCloud-double:A-TangoXyzIjData-) that gets double[], but it doesn't exist in my version.

2. So to avoid it I converted my float[] to double[] and called the `TangoSupport.transformPointCloud` function that expects double[], but now I get another weird error, which seems related:

06-15 15:04:10.191 9313-9399/com.projecttango.experiments.javapointcloud A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: attempt to set field java.nio.FloatBuffer com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoXyzIjData.xyz with value of wrong type: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oren, it looks like there's a mis-match in documentation, but I checked transformPointCloud interface, it take in double[] instead of float. The error looks like there's something wrong with your xyzij data, is the xyzij data you passed in is valid?

Comment: It's the xyzij that I get from the callback, and it looks valid.

But the type mismatch (java.nio.FloatBuffer vs java.nio.DirectByteBuffer) makes me think that there's another interface mismatch, maybe more internal one.

Comment: I have the same error, and I'm sure that my data is valid

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `TangoSupport.initialize();`

After upgrading to Okul library we had similar problem.

All we just had to do was to initialise support library in this new release.

Comment: Added it, didn't help.